# rails rack-protection usage, error "you need to set up a session middleware *before* Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i tried to use the gem rack-protection, i followed the usage guide to configure the "config.ru" file. when i try to run the app again i got this ERROR "**you need to set up a session middleware *before* Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking**".

```
  # config.ru
  require 'rack/protection'
  use Rack::Protection
  run MyApp
```

By take the code from reply:

```
module YouApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking
```

i put this into my application.rb and still getting the Internal Service Error **you need to set up a session middleware before Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking**

Here is the output of rake middleware:

```
use Rack::MiniProfiler
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007f9482a28910>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActiveRecord::SessionStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use ActionDispatch::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
use Warden::Manager
use Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking
use MetaRequest::Middlewares::MetaRequestHandler
use MetaRequest::Middlewares::Headers
use MetaRequest::Middlewares::AppRequestHandler
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
run Myapp::Application.routes
```

Appreciate for anyone can help and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 is to exclude SessionHijacking middleware from the Rack::Protection pack:

```
# config.ru
require 'rack/protection'
use Rack::Protection, :except => :session_hijacking
...
run YourApp
```

This will solve the problem - but I will assume you really want this Anti-hijacking feature:

Step 2. Add the middleware inside Rails application.rb

```
module YouApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking
    ...
```

In this way you will make it load after rails own session middleware - ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore.

You can check the result by running `rake middleware`

Comment: Hi, I just see this repley and firstly, thanks for getting back.  I have tried to configure the **config.middleware.use Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking** you mentioned, but still getting this Internal Service Error: you need to set up a session middleware *before* Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking. any thing i can do to fix that? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer of @dip00dip,

Do this:

```
# config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Protection
```

Don't use config.ru. This is the way recommended in the Rails Guides to use Rack Middleware.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack